# How can I find the index of all NA in a dataframe column?

Tags: r, dataframe, missing-data

I have a dataframe and in a particular column I want to find the index of all **NA** values. How can I do it?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
which(is.na(my.df$col.I.care.about))
```